# a list of HighShools, Universities in Europe, South America and Asia

Tags: data

i am looking for a list of HighShools, Universities in Europe, South America and Asia

is there a dataset that is free - and available!?

**OpenStreetMap (OSM):** OpenStreetMap is a collaborative mapping project that provides free and open geographic data. You can extract data from OSM to get information about schools and universities worldwide. The data is available in various formats, including XML, CSV, and shapefiles. You can use the Overpass API or download pre-extracted datasets from websites like Geofabrik.

**UNESCO Institute for Statistics (UIS):** The UIS provides comprehensive data on education, including information about schools and universities worldwide. They offer a variety of datasets and publications that you can access for free. Visit the UIS Data Centre (data.uis.unesco.org) to explore their available datasets.

**European Commission's Education, Audiovisual, and Culture Executive Agency (EACEA):** The EACEA provides datasets related to education in Europe, including information about schools and universities. Their datasets cover various aspects of education, such as institutions, programs, and funding. You can access their data through the EACEA website (eacea.ec.europa.eu).

**Data.gov:** Data.gov is a platform that provides access to a wide range of datasets from various government agencies in the United States. While the focus is primarily on US data, they also offer some international datasets, including educational data. You can search their catalog and filter by location to find relevant datasets.

**World Bank Open Data**: The World Bank provides open data on various topics, including education. While the data may not be as extensive as specialized education sources, you can find information about schools and universities in different countries. Visit the World Bank Open Data website (data.worldbank.org) and explore the education-related datasets.

Comment: only public, but also private-for-profit, private-non-profit? Range of subjects and majors is much larger for Private Institutes (you can get a degree in astrology for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of universities(not all) on World Higher Education database which is in collaboration with UNESCO. You can search here country wise : https://www.whed.net/home.php.

Comment: many thanks for the hints - awesome

Comment: [Study In EU](https://www.study.eu/) Here, you can browse list of universities in Europe by Subject.

Comment: [International School Database](https://www.international-schools-database.com/) Here, you can search for schools in Europe, Africa and Middle East.